# Beaglebone Black ADC sampling with libpruio

Tags: c, timer, interrupt, beagleboneblack, adc

I'm doing a project on a Beaglebone Black where i need 4 ADC channels to sample at 40khz each. I have installed the libpruio library and able to sample the ADC channels.

My question is how to set up timer interrupts on the board to get that specific sampling rate. I cannot seem to find good documentation to do so.

Comment: It's unlikely to find it here as well.

Comment: fingers crossed then

Comment: You may want to ask questions related to embedded systems or microcontrollers in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90111/embedded-systems

Answer (score 1):

Timer interrupts are slow. libpruio is designed to read the samples from a ring buffer. Configure sampling in RB mode and check the counter.

Find an examples and further information by googling for:

libpruio "rb_file"